# JsGrid failing to coerce value on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I'm trying to coerce a format value into the column "Import" when editing. It should be a string that represents a number with exactly 2 fixed decimal digits. Example: `1152.30`. Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

**JS code**

```
const ACCOUNT_GRID_FIELD_NAME = "account";
const IMPORT_GRID_FIELD_NAME = "import";

$("#grid").jsGrid(createGridConfiguration());

function createGridConfiguration() {
  let result;

  result = {
    inserting: false,
    editing: true,
    sorting: false,
    paging: false,

    data: [],

    onItemInserting: onGridItemInserting,
    onItemUpdating: onGridItemUpdating,

    fields: [{
      name: ACCOUNT_GRID_FIELD_NAME,
      title: "Account",
      type: "text",
      width: 300,
    }, {
      name: IMPORT_GRID_FIELD_NAME,
      title: "Import",
      type: "text",
      width: 200,
    }, {
      type: "control",
      width: 150,
      editButton: true,
      modeSwitchButton: false,
      headerTemplate: onRenderAddRowHeadder,
    }]
  }

  return result;
}

function onGridItemInserting(args) {
  let validAmount;

  validAmount = formatAmountForOutput(0);
  args.item[IMPORT_GRID_FIELD_NAME] = validAmount;
}

function onGridItemUpdating(args) {
  let validAmount, previousAmount;

  previousAmount = args.item[IMPORT_GRID_FIELD_NAME];
  validAmount = formatAmountForOutput(previousAmount);
  args.item[IMPORT_GRID_FIELD_NAME] = validAmount; // Here we have the correct value
}

function formatAmountForOutput(amount) {
  let result, valueAsNumber;

  if (amount === undefined) {
    valueAsNumber = 0;
  } else {
    valueAsNumber = parseFloat(amount);
    if (isNaN(valueAsNumber)) {
      valueAsNumber = 0;
    }
  }

  result = valueAsNumber.toFixed(2);

  return result;
}

function onRenderAddRowHeadder() {
  let result;

  result = $("<input>");
  result.addClass("jsgrid-button jsgrid-insert-button")
  result.attr("type", "button");
  result.on("click", onGridInsertItemClick);

  return result;
}

function onGridInsertItemClick() {
  let grid;

  grid = $("#grid");
  grid.jsGrid("insertItem");
}
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warcraker/q3oLvhq2/)**

When I click on insert, it fires `onGridItemInserting`, so it inserts the correct value, but when I try to use the same technique on edit, if fires `onGridItemUpdating`, and generates the correct value (look at commented line), but the grid (and the data inside it) ends with the incorrect value.

Example: I click on insert, and a "0.00" appears. That is correct. Now I click on that "0.00", and modify it so I write "120.1234". When I click on confirm, I expect to become "120.12", but it stores and shows "120.1234".

**How can I coerce the desired value?**

Answer (score 1):

> Its fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/rn30w2r0/

I see on the doc that after editing you have to refresh the grid, take a look at the jsGrid github. Using `$("#grid").jsGrid("refresh");` [GitHub](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/754#issuecomment-298336657)

And another one you have set the wrong data on

```
args.item[IMPORT_GRID_FIELD_NAME] = validAmount;
```

Thank you

Comment: I put the JSFiddle, you could have tried for yourself ;) Anyway: 
[click insert]2.valueAsNumber:0 - [modify and confirm]
(index):130 1.previousAmount:123.123
(index):154 2.valueAsNumber:123.123
(index):132 3.validAmount:123.12
(index):134 4.args:123.12

Comment: your jsfiddle not showing anything from here :) the grid out Not Found

Comment: That is because it has no data at start. You have to click on the big green +

Comment: see the fiddle on my answer

Comment: If I modify the account column it remains empty

Comment: It has a problem when updating the value multiple times.This is how to replicate: 1) Click add. 2) Click pencil. 3) Select import and write, exactly, 5. 4) Click pencil. 5) Click ok. 

Now repeat 4 and 5 and you will see that it cycles between `5` and `5.00`. It should always be `5.00`

Comment: By the way, you could add this line on the CSS box to fix the grid size: 

`#grid { width:auto !important; }`